# How to rename a component column that is a foreign key?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, components, automapping

We are using fluentnhibernate with automapping and we have a naming convention that all columns that are foreign keys, there column name will end with "Key". So we have a convention that looks like this:

```
public class ForeignKeyColumnNameConvention : IReferenceConvention
{
    public void Apply ( IManyToOneInstance instance )
    {
        // name the key field
        string propertyName = instance.Property.Name;

        instance.Column ( propertyName + "Key" );
    }
}
```

This works great until we created a component in which one of its values is a foreign key. By renaming the column here it overrides the default name given to the component column which includes the ComponentPrefix which is defined in the AutomappingConfiguration. Is there a way for me to get the ComponentPrefix in this convention? or is there some other way for me to get the column name for components with a property that is a foreign key to end in the word "Key"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have figured out a way to do this using reflection to get to the underlying mapping of the IManyToOneInspector exposed by the IComponentInstance but was hoping there was a better way to do this?

Here is some example code of how I achieved this:

```
#region IConvention<IComponentInspector, IComponentInstance> Members 
    public void Apply(IComponentInstance instance) 
    { 
        foreach (var manyToOneInspector in instance.References) 
        { 
            var referenceName = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}{3}", instance.EntityType.Name, manyToOneInspector.Property.PropertyType.Name, _autoMappingConfiguration.GetComponentColumnPrefix(instance.Property), manyToOneInspector.Property.Name); 
            if(manyToOneInspector.Property.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(LookupBase))) 
            { 
                referenceName += "Lkp"; 
            } 
            manyToOneInspector.Index ( string.Format ( "{0}_FK_IDX", referenceName ) ); 
        } 
    } 
#endregion 
public static class ManyToOneInspectorExtensions 
{ 
    public static ManyToOneMapping GetMapping(this IManyToOneInspector manyToOneInspector) 
    { 
        var fieldInfo = manyToOneInspector.GetType ().GetField( "mapping", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance ); 
        if (fieldInfo != null) 
        { 
            var manyToOneMapping = fieldInfo.GetValue( manyToOneInspector ) as ManyToOneMapping; 
            return manyToOneMapping; 
        } 
        return null; 
    } 
    public static void Index(this IManyToOneInspector manyToOneInspector, string indexName) 
    { 
        var mapping = manyToOneInspector.GetMapping (); 
        mapping.Index ( indexName ); 
    } 
    public static void Column(this IManyToOneInspector manyToOneInspector, string columnName) 
    { 
        var mapping = manyToOneInspector.GetMapping (); 
        mapping.Column ( columnName ); 
    } 
    public static void ForeignKey(this IManyToOneInspector manyToOneInspector, string foreignKeyName) 
    { 
        var mapping = manyToOneInspector.GetMapping(); 
        mapping.ForeignKey ( foreignKeyName ); 
    } 
} 
public static class ManyToOneMappingExtensions 
{ 
    public static void Index (this ManyToOneMapping manyToOneMapping, string indexName) 
    { 
        if (manyToOneMapping.Columns.First().IsSpecified("Index")) 
            return; 
        foreach (var column in manyToOneMapping.Columns) 
        { 
            column.Index = indexName; 
        } 
    } 
    public static void Column(this ManyToOneMapping manyToOneMapping, string columnName) 
    { 
        if (manyToOneMapping.Columns.UserDefined.Count() > 0) 
            return; 
        var originalColumn = manyToOneMapping.Columns.FirstOrDefault(); 
        var column = originalColumn == null ? new ColumnMapping() : originalColumn.Clone(); 
        column.Name = columnName; 
        manyToOneMapping.ClearColumns(); 
        manyToOneMapping.AddColumn(column); 
    } 
    public static void ForeignKey(this ManyToOneMapping manyToOneMapping, string foreignKeyName) 
    { 
        if (!manyToOneMapping.IsSpecified("ForeignKey")) 
            manyToOneMapping.ForeignKey = foreignKeyName; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of fiddling and trial & error (thus being tempted to use your solution with Reflection) I came up with the following:

This method depends on the order of the execution of the conventions. This convention-order happens via a strict hierarchy. In this example, at first, the convention of the component (`IDynamicComponentConvention`) is being handled and after that the conventions of the inner properties are being handled such as the References mapping (`IReferenceConvention`).

The strict order is where we make our strike:

1. We assemble the correct name of the column in the call to `Apply(IDynamicComponentConvention instance)`, put it on the queue. *Note that a `Queue<T>` is used which is a FIFO (first-in-first-out) collection type thus it keeps the order correctly.*
2. Almost immediately after that, `Apply(IManyToOneInstanceinstance)` is called. We check if there is anything in the queue. If there is, we take it out of the queue and set it as column name. *Note that you should not use `Peek()` instead of `Dequeue()` as it does not remove the object from the queue.*

The code is as follows:

```
public sealed class CustomNamingConvention : IDynamicComponentConvention, IReferenceConvention {
    private static Queue<string> ColumnNames = new Queue<string>();

    public void Apply(IDynamicComponentInstance instance) {
        foreach (var referenceInspector in instance.References) {
            // All the information we need is right here
            // But only to inspect, no editing yet :(
            // Don't worry, just assemble the name and enqueue it
            var name = string.Format("{0}_{1}",
                instance.Name,
                referenceInspector.Columns.Single().Name);
            ColumnNames.Enqueue(name);
        }
    }

    public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance) {
        if (!ColumnNames.Any())
            // Nothing in the queue? Just return then (^_^)
            return;

        // Set the retrieved string as the column name
        var columnName = ColumnNames.Dequeue();
        instance.Column(columnName);

        // Pick a beer and celebrate the correct naming!
    }
}
```